# Mapping an index from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, indexing

I am trying to have a code that will return a random sentence from an array. Kind of like a random quote machine except it’s 3 different quotes on the page at the same time.
Here’s how it looks

```
<div className="">
          {this.state.first.map((first) => (
            <div className="">{first}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="">
          {this.state.second.map((second) => (
            <div className="">{second}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="">
          {this.state.third.map((third) => (
            <div className="">{third}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

What I want to do is have the map function only return one from each array. I tried this by doing this.

```
 {this.state.first.map((first) => (
            <div className="">{first[0]}</div>
          ))}
```

This gave me the first letter from each sentence. But what am I missing to have it give me the whole sentence returning instead of just the first letter?
The whole code is viewable here
https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/CovidConspiracyGenerator/blob/master/src/Slotmachine.jsx
Thank you in advance for your input.

Edit for clarification. I want to have a random index of each array display to the page when a user presses a button. I already have a function that will give me a random number between 1 and 10. I want to be able to have it work like a random quote machine.

Comment: you are most probably having a wrong approach, have an object instead which propertis will have an array value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want one element from the array of sentences, access one of the indicies of the `.first`, `.second`, `.third` arrays instead of trying to `.map` them. For example:

```
<div>{this.state.first[0]}</div>
<div>{this.state.second[0]}</div>
<div>{this.state.third[0]}</div>
```

More likely, you'd want to save the current index being displayed in state, and have something like:

```
<div>{this.state.first[this.state.firstIndex]}</div>
<div>{this.state.second[this.state.secondIndex]}</div>
<div>{this.state.third[this.state.thirdIndex]}</div>
```

where `firstIndex` will be a number from 0 to `n - 1`, where `n` is the length of `this.state.first`, and so on for the second and third. To select a new random quote in `first`, you'd do:

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  firstIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.first.length)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your solution of having it not map works, however I am trying to have it map dynamically in a function that can be called again.  Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *I am trying to have it map dynamically in a function that can be called again*, can you edit your question to clarify? Since you only want one sentence from each bunch, using `.map` at all doesn't make sense - instead, put the current index being displayed into state, and call `setState` to change to a different index.

Comment: "instead, put the current index being displayed into state, and call setState to change to a different index."
I think I will do this, it's a much better idea. Thank you.